# Elastic Search Alternative of SQL Query?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

How can I write a `Elastic Search Alternative` of the following SQL Query,

```
select
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    count(column3)
from
    table_name
where
    some conditions
group by
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
order by
    column 3 desc;
```

I tried many ways by facets, sum aggregations, etc. Not able to combine the query.
I thought same can be done using scripts, but I am unaware how to do?

1. Can you please guide me on how to write the above SQL alternative?
2. Is it possible via scripts, if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do it but only by one group by column. Here's the query

```
{
  "index": "index_value",
  "type": "type_value",
  "searchQuery": {
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "activity_date": {
          "from": "2013-11-01",
          "to": "2014-11-02"
        }
      }
    },
    "facets": {
      "sample_facet": {
        "terms_stats": {
          "key_field": "offering_sku",
          "value_field": "net_ordered_units",
          "value_field": "gross_ordered_units",
          "order": "max"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

specify the where conditions in the filter, and facet is group by alternative of elasticsearch where the `key_field` refers the column name and `value_field` refers the field where aggregation is performed like sum, max,etc. Order which is max refers it is sorted based on maximum value that is descending order.